# How can I get a remote computer to automatically render a blender file

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a computer at home that I want to use for rendering so I can continue using my laptop.
Is there a way I can send a blend file to my Desktop which will automatically be opened and rendered for me.

Comment: You can try using VNC or other kind of remote software like teamviewer (do not use Microsoft's Remote Desktop, as it cannot do OpenGL properly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is. Automatically scheduling it will be a bit of a hassle, though (if you want to do that).

---

## Rendering it

Blender can actually be run from the command line (Terminal on Mac, cmd on Windows). You can render a file like this:

```
blender -b path/to/file.blend -o whatever-####.png
```

On Mac, prefix this with `/Applications/Blender/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/` (replace `/Applications/Blender` with wherever you installed Blender). I don't know what to prefix it with on Windows.

Try this out, and it should spit out a .png image file in the current directory (another name for folder), which should be your home folder.

## Rendering it remotely (on Mac)

You can just transfer the file to the remote machine and run the above command. This is for controlling it from the work machine.

Open a terminal on the rendering machine and type `hostname`. (You only need to do this once.) Then go to your work machine and type `ping whatever.local`, where `whatever.local` is the output of the hostname command on the other machine. You should get a continuous stream of output. Hit Ctrl-C to stop it. This step is to make sure that the two computers can see each other.

Now run this command, which does something very interesting:

```
ssh yourusername@whatever.local
```

`yourusername` is your username on the **remote** machine.

It'll give you a scary "identity could not be verified" warning the first time you connect. Just type "yes" to continue. (It can't tell the difference between a new machine and an impostor.)

Assuming you got your other machine's password correct, you are now *controlling the remote machine*!

Now copy the file to your render machine, or run this command:

```
scp yourworkusername@work-machine.local:/Users/.../file.blend ~
```

This will pull the file to your home folder on the remote machine. (Run `hostname` in another window to get your work machine's name.)

Now run the `blender` command above. Repeat `scp` and `blender` as necessary. When you're done for the day, type `exit` to log out of the remote machine.

Comment: How would I do this on a windows machine?

Comment: The `blender` command will still work on Windows, so you can transfer the file another way and run the command there. (`blender` should be prefixed with wherever it's installed; I just don't know where it installs to on Windows, if anywhere.)

Comment: Windows 10 actually has built-in SSH now, but it's disabled by default. (See [here](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/heres-how-to-enable-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-client/) for instructions on enabling it.)

Answer (score 0):

If u use a hard drive and put the blend file plus any textures in the same folder u could build it on the laptop and then just plug the hard drive into the pc. Then just open it and press render

Comment: But how can i do this if i am not at home, sorry should of specified is there an automated system